# perl regular expression extract ip from router show output

Tags: regex, perl

I have this output from router command:

```
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
POS0/0/0               10.137.99.2    YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

I want to find a regular expression to identify the IP-Address:

I tried with:

```
if ( $_ =~ m/(.*?)\s*?(.*?)\s*?(.*?)\s*?(.*)/i ){
    #print "$1->$2\n";
    $sources{$2}=$1;
}
```

and then use `$2` as ip.

However, it does not work; where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PacoRG's answer works nicely, but to explain where yours is going wrong:

Remember that `*` *can* match *no occurrences*. You're telling each group to match as little as possible, so the first 3 groups are capturing nothing. Further, you want to grab as *many* consecutive whitespace characters as possible, not as few.

Keeping with a RegEx somewhat like your original, you could use

```
m/(.+?)\s+(.+?)\s+(.+?)\s+(.+?)/i
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if ($_ =~ /\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b/)
{
        print "IP: $1\n";
}
```

If you just want to obtain the second column, then may be you should use `split` instead of regular expressions. To obtain field #2:

```
@field = split(/ +/, $_);
print "$field[1]";
```

Comment: But I want to do it more abstract, want the second column. Considering that each column is divided by white space.

Comment: Or better: `$ip = (split)[1];`

Answer (score 2):

Since this is regularly formatted data, you could probably just use split: and get at it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Modern::Perl;


my $buff = "Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
POS0/0/0               10.137.99.2    YES NVRAM  up                    up  ";

for my $line (split /\n/,$buff)
{
  next if $line =~ /^Interface/;
  my ($interface, $ip) = (split /\s+/,$line)[0,1];
  say "IP $ip is on Interface $interface";
}
```

which produces this output:

```
IP 10.137.99.2 is on Interface POS0/0/0
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is all those minimal matches.  Just use

```
($if, $ip) = split;
$sources{$ip} = $if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
m/.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*/i
```